Assets with spaces in name causing issue in admin
On one of my clients sites I am getting an issue with spaces in asset names. For example

This is the file uploaded: Plan of a Court.jpg
If i click to preview in a browser it changes the spaces to '%20' but works ok
Plan%20of%20a%20Court.jpg
If i click on the asset to goto the detail page it gives me a 403 error with this url /admin/assets/edit/9674-Plan%20of%20a%20Court
If i change the '%20' to '-' it works fine then e.g. /admin/assets/edit/9674-Plan-of-a-Court

It seems like i need to do some kind of batch change to correct this for my client maybe? (They have a lot of assets)

Craft CMS has a console command utils/ascii-filenames which should do what you need: convert all non ASCII filenames to ASCII filenames which should work on any server.
Additionally there's a config parameter, which should do this right after upload. ->convertFilenamesToAscii(true)
See https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/reference/config/general.html#convertfilenamestoascii

Thanks Max, will give it a try

Hi Max, I tried this out and it seemed to change some file names and not others no idea why. It found 10 files to change (when i can see there are a lot more than that).
I have put a couple of example file names below that were not changed incase this sheds any light and i need a different command?!
Image 3_ Tonbridge School.jpg
Image 2_ Cheltenham Ladies' College.jpg
Image 4_ Marlborough College.jpg

Did you try to update the search indexes and rerun the command after?

I resaved all the assets using 'php craft resave/assets --update-search-index' and then ran 'php craft utils/ascii-filenames' but found no assets with non-ASCII filenames

Hey, sorry I meant the asset indexes (php craft index-assets/all).
